# Enqueued script fails

Tags: javascript, child-theme, wp-enqueue-script

```
function my_scripts_method() {
wp_enqueue_script(
      'custom-script',
      get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/js/custom_script.js 
      array( 'query' ),'',true );
     
   
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_script.js' );
```

Ive tried putting this code in functions.php and header.php to call the javascript. doesn't work

The countdown javascript animation is in a file named custom_script.js in a folder named js, which is in the child theme folder named wpbdemo.
The animation also had css and html, but that is working I think, as the countdown template is showing, its just not doing any movement. So, I think its the javascript code not working.
The css is in style.css file and the html is in footer.php.

Comment: Is the code you posted here the actual code you're using? As you can see from the formatting, there are a couple of problems with it to run successful.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Comment: My guess is that you're getting a file not found error (which you can confirm in dev tools. Look for red text in the console saying "Failed to load resource"). 

The likely cause is that your relative file path is incorrect. Are you adding this enqueue code to the parent or child functions.php? The path to your script will differ depending on which theme it's being added to.